# TCPReplay - Time Interval between loops

Tags: pcap, tcpreplay

tcpreplay -i eth1 --pktlen -p3200 -l10 Sample.pcap

Above it the command I am using, I need to replay packets at good speeds, but I also need it to take a break of about 20 seconds before next round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple little shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
    tcpreplay -i eth1 --pktlen -p 3200 Sample.pcap
    i=$(($i + 1))
    sleep 20
done
```